# Tkinter : How to draw new lines when tkinter button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

I'm working a python project where i want to draw lines and move only the latest line when a button is clicked multiple times.
I currently am able to draw click of this button and drag this line with my mouse cursor, but when i click again i want to be able to draw a new line which is moveable too.

Code :

---

```
from tkinter import *  
import tkinter 
root = Tk()     
root.geometry('400x650')        

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width = 480,height = 600) 


def draw_lines():
    canvas.create_line(300, 35, 300, 200, dash=(4, 2))

def drag(event):
    event.widget.place(x=event.x_root, y=event.y_root,anchor=CENTER)


canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)

btn1 = Button(root, text = 'line', bd = '5',command = draw_lines)
btn2 = Button(root, text = 'Close', bd = '5',command = root.destroy)

btn1.pack(side = 'top')   
btn2.pack(side = 'top')

canvas.pack()
canvas.mainloop()
```

---

Any help is appreciated,

This is my post where i've highlighted other problems on the same code :

[Problems while drawing straight line and dragging in Tkinter canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73453180/problems-while-drawing-straight-line-and-dragging-in-tkinter-canvas)

Comment: As the comment in your linked question, your code is dragging the canvas widget, not the line.  Also you do not clearly describe *where the new line will be drawn*.  Actually your code will create a new line at the same position when the `line` button is clicked.

Comment: How do i bind the line drawn to drag function?